# How to delete characters at x?

Tags: java

How to delete the characters at x and keep the rest? The output should be "12345678" Deleting every '9' in the position that x is on. X is i*(i+1)/2 so that the number is added to the next number. So every number at 0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,etc.

```
public class removeMysteryI {
    public static String removeMysteryI(String str) {
       String newString = "";
       int x=0;
       for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        int y = (i*(i+1)/2)+1;
        if(y<=str.length()){
            x=i*(i+1)/2;
            newString=str.substring(0, x) + str.substring(x + 1);            
        }
       }
        return newString;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "9919239456978";
        System.out.println(removeMysteryI(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add more details? what does `x` mean?

Comment: What is the meaning of `y`?

Comment: @peer The is the same as x but If I had the x outside of the if statement it would go on too long past what the string had in it. I have it there to keep it the same length as the string.

Comment: @Horse The x is every position in the string I want to be deleted. So it would be 0, 1, 3, 6, 10.

Comment: Anything wrong with just `str.replace("9", "")`?

Comment: @Bohemian The explanation in the question is not clear. Please look at my answer below. will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below:

1. Initialize with `builderIndexToDelete = 0`
2. Initialize with `counter = 1`
3. Repeat the following till the index is valid:
4. delete character at `builderIndexToDelete`
5. update `builderIndexToDelete` to `counter - 1` (-1 as a character is deleted in every iteration)
6. increment the counter

```java
    public static String deleteNaturalSumIndexes(String str) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
        int counter = 1;
        int builderIndexToDelete = 0;
        while (builderIndexToDelete < builder.length()) {
            builder.deleteCharAt(builderIndexToDelete);
            builderIndexToDelete += (counter - 1);
            counter++;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "9919239456978";
        System.out.println(deleteNaturalSumIndexes(str));
    }
```

Thank you @dreamcrash and @StephenC

### Using @StephenC suggestion to improve performance

```java
    public static String deleteNaturalSumIndexes(String str) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int nextNum = 1;
        int indexToDelete = 0;
        while (indexToDelete < str.length()) {
            // check whether this is a valid range to continue
            // handles 0,1 specifically
            if (indexToDelete + 1 < indexToDelete + nextNum) {
                // min is used to limit the index of last iteration
                builder.append(str, indexToDelete + 1, Math.min(indexToDelete + nextNum, str.length()));
            }
            indexToDelete += nextNum;
            nextNum++;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(deleteNaturalSumIndexes(""));
        System.out.println(deleteNaturalSumIndexes("a"));
        System.out.println(deleteNaturalSumIndexes("ab"));
        System.out.println(deleteNaturalSumIndexes("abc"));
        System.out.println(deleteNaturalSumIndexes("99192394569"));
        System.out.println(deleteNaturalSumIndexes("9919239456978"));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Note that just giving a student the solution is not going to help them learn.  It is more helpful if you help them understand what they did wrong, so that they can learn to solve these problems themselves.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you. I will add more explanation and help them identify the actual problem

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there are a couple of mistakes in your code.  One is easy to fix.  The others not so easy.

The easy one first:

```
 newString=str.substring(0, x) + str.substring(x + 1);
```

OK so that is creating a string with the character at position `x` removed.  The problem is what it is operating on.  The `str` variable is the input parameter.  So at the end of the day `newString` will still only be `str` with one character removed.

The above actually needs to be operating on the string from the previous loop iterations ... if you are going to remove more than one character.

The next problem arises when you try to solve the first one.  When you remove a character from a string, all characters after the removal point are renumbered; e.g. after removing the character at 5, the character at 6 becomes the character at 5, the character at 7 becomes the character at 6, and so on.

So if you are going to remove characters by "snipping" the string, you need to make sure that the indexes for the positions for the "snips" are adjusted for the number of characters you have already removed.

That can be done ... but you need to think about it.

The final problem is efficiency.  Each time your current code removes a single character (as above), it is actually copying all remaining characters to a new string.  For small strings, that's OK.  For really large strings, the repeated copying could have a serious performance impact<sup>1</sup>.

The solution to this is to use a different approach to removing the characters.  Instead of snipping out the characters you want to discard, copy the characters that you want to keep.   The `StringBuilder` class is one way of doing this<sup>2</sup>.  If you are not permitted to use that, then you *could* do it with an array of `char`, and an index variable to keep track of your "append" position in the array.  Finally, there is a `String` constructor that can create a `String` from the relevant part of the `char[]`.

I'll leave it to you to work out the details.

---

<sup>1 - Efficiency could be viewed as beyond the scope of this exercise.  

2 - @Horse's answer uses a `StringBuilder` but in a different way to what I am suggesting.  This will also suffer from the repeated copying problem because each `deleteCharAt` call will copy all characters after the deletion point.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for sharing about the optimization.